# SharePoint Online appoval workflow not starting when publishing a major version by checking in a document via the ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have a document library setup with publishing in SharePoint Online. It is set to run the approval workflow when a Major version is published after checking in a document.

The problem is that when i check in the document via the ribbon and select publish major version, the approval workflow does not start and it returns to the document library where the approval status is set to Pending. It does not open up the approval form where you select who should approve it.

However if I right click on the document in the library, select Advanced, then Check In, the workflow starts properly and the content approval form appears. I do not know why it behaves differently when checking in the document from the ribbon or the item menu?

In the workflow settings I have the 'Allow this workflow to be manually started by an authenticated user with Edit Item permissions' checkbox checked.

Can anybody shed any light on this as to how I can get the approval workflow to work correctly when checking in and publishing via the ribbon?